# JSTree: simply create node

Tags: jstree

I want to create a node with JSTree. 
The HTML:

```
<div id="tree">
    <ul>
      <li>a<ul>
            <li>b</li>
            <li>c</li>
            <li>d</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the JQuery:

```
var  root = $("#tree").jstree();
$("#tree").jstree(true).create_node(root,"root1");
```

It displays the tree but not create the root1. What's missing?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

To add a node at the root level you have to use `#` as the parent id. Try this:

```
$("#tree").jstree(true).create_node("#","root1");
```